# Calling Method on an array

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me understand what is going on in this code?

```
   function reduce(fn, a, init){

    var s = init;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        s = fn( s, a[i] );
    return s;
}

function sum(a)
{
    return reduce( function(a, b){ return a + b; }, 
                   a, 0 );
}

function join(a)
{
    return reduce( function(a, b){ return a + b; }, 
                   a, "" );
}
```

I guess the part that is throwing me of is the b variable and how it is used. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should probably add a `var` before the `i = 0` in the `for` loop; otherwise, `reduce` won't work recursively.

Answer (score 2):

The reduce function takes some operator, •, which is implemented by `fn`, and computes the result of applying • to all the elements in turn:

```
reduce(•, [a, b, c, d, e], init) = init • a • b • c • d • e
```

In the case of sum, the operator implemented by `fn` is `+`, so you end up with `init + a + b + c + d + e`. Likewise for join (except that, over strings, `+` concatenates).

Answer (score 0):

It is calling the function on every element in the array, passing the init (which is being updated on each iteration) and current array member.

It then returns the `s` value, which is the return from the values being passed through the function passed.

The `sum()` works because `init` is `0` (`Number`), so they are treated as `Number`s.

The `join()` works because it passes an empty `String` (`""`), so they are treated as `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

the function `reduce()` is an aggregator function, executing the passed function `fn` on every element of the passed array `a` and passing a state (which initially has the value of `init`) along with it, representing the result of the previous call.

In the case of `sum()` i.e. it's summing up all elements of the array by passing the sum of all previous elements (`s`) to the next function call so the "aggregate" is the sum of all elements.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is a parameter to the anonymous function (`fn`) being passed to reduce.  That function simply combines two values and returns the result.  The `reduce` function calls `fn` repeatedly to combine the array into a single value.  Note that the `a` parameter to `reduce` is not the same as the `a` parameter to the anonymous function.

EDIT: The example you requested:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var mySum = sum(myArray);
```

Note that `sum` uses `reduce`.

Comment: how would I go about calling this reduce method on an array if it is already declared and what not so it adds up all of the elements and show result?

Comment: @Spence, I posted an example.

Answer (score 0):

[@Marcelo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774885/calling-method-on-an-array/5774927#5774927) is probably the best and most general explanation for this piece of code - that's the one you're looking for.

---

A. When invoked via `sum`, the function `reduce` gets 3 parameters

- `fn` the function that sums two numbers
- `a`, an array of numbers to be summed
- `b`, the initial sum (set to `0`)

  ```
  function reduce(fn, a, init){
  ```

  1. `s` is initialized to the intial sum value

     ```
     var s = init;
     ```
  2. For each element in `a`:

     ```
     for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
     ```
  3. The sum is calculated by invoking `fn` to add the last sum calculated, `s`, and the current element of the array `a[i]`

     ```
     s = fn( s, a[i] );
     ```
  4. And this sum is returned once all array elements have been added to `s`

     ```
     return s;
     }
     ```

B. When invoked via `join`, the function `reduce` gets 3 parameters

- `fn` the function that concatenates two strings
- `a`, an array of values to be concatenated
- `b`, the initial string (the empty string `""`)

It does pretty much the same as explained above except it returns a string which is the concatenation of all values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
// All new browsers implement a native reduce method for arrays-
// it might be better to shim older browsers to use the same method,
// so that you can use the native method where available.

if(!Array.prototype.reduce){
    Array.prototype.reduce= function(fun, temp, scope){
        var i= 0, T= this, len= T.length, temp;
        if(scope== undefined) scope= window;
        if(typeof fun=== 'function'){
            if(temp== undefined) temp= T[i++];
            while(i < len){
                if(i in T) temp= fun.call(scope, temp, T[i], i, T);
                i++;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
    Array.prototype.reduceRight= function(fun, temp, scope){
        var T= this.concat().reverse();
        return T.reduce(fun, temp, scope);
    }
}

var A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
/*  A.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b});
value: (Number)55

A.reduce(function(a,b){return a*b});
 value: (Number)3628800
*/
```